# Are these upgrades all Jessie related, none are Stretch or Buster?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, apt

RASPBIAN JESSIE:
I recently did a full update and then upgrade of apt. So eventhing was up to date.
I then decided I needed some advance s/w and hence uncommented this line in /etc/apt/sources.list to get a stretch repo.

```
#deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main
```

I then ran: `$ sudo apt-get update`

I then decided I did not want the advanced s/w from this new source.
So I commented the line again
Re-ran the update command, I do not think it did anything, upgradable seems the same.

Below is the result of listing my upgradable, I am worried all these will upgrade when really everything is upgraded and I do not want anything additional.

**I am currently on Jessie are all these upgrades Jessie?**

upgradable list:

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
apt-transport-https/oldoldstable 1.0.9.8.5 armhf [upgradable from: 1.0.9.8.4]
apt-utils/oldoldstable 1.0.9.8.5 armhf [upgradable from: 1.0.9.8.4]
bind9-host/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
ca-certificates/oldoldstable 20141019+deb8u4 all [upgradable from: 20141019+deb8u3]
cpio/oldoldstable 2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.11+dfsg-4.1+deb8u1]
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm/oldoldstable 7u241-2.6.20-1~deb8u1+rpi1 armhf [upgradable from: 7u151-2.6.11-1~deb8u1+rpi1]
isc-dhcp-client/oldoldstable 4.3.1-6+deb8u4 armhf [upgradable from: 4.3.1-6+deb8u2]
isc-dhcp-common/oldoldstable 4.3.1-6+deb8u4 armhf [upgradable from: 4.3.1-6+deb8u2]
libbind9-90/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libdns100/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libglib2.0-data/oldoldstable 2.42.1-1+deb8u3 all [upgradable from: 2.42.1-1]
libio-socket-ssl-perl/oldoldstable 2.002-2+deb8u3 all [upgradable from: 2.002-2+deb8u2]
libisc95/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libisccc90/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libisccfg90/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libjs-jquery/oldoldstable 1.7.2+dfsg-3.2+deb8u7 all [upgradable from: 1.7.2+dfsg-3.2]
liblwres90/oldoldstable 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u18 armhf [upgradable from: 1:9.9.5.dfsg-9+deb8u13]
libsasl2-modules/oldoldstable 2.1.26.dfsg1-13+deb8u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.1.26.dfsg1-13+deb8u1]
mumble-server/oldoldstable 1.2.8-2+deb8u1 armhf [upgradable from: 1.2.8-2]
ncurses-term/oldoldstable 5.9+20140913-1+deb8u3 all [upgradable from: 5.9+20140913-1]
nfs-common/oldoldstable 1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1 armhf [upgradable from: 1:1.2.8-9]
nfs-kernel-server/oldoldstable 1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1 armhf [upgradable from: 1:1.2.8-9]
openjdk-7-jre-headless/oldoldstable 7u241-2.6.20-1~deb8u1+rpi1 armhf [upgradable from: 7u151-2.6.11-1~deb8u1+rpi1]
opensc/oldoldstable 0.16.0-3+deb8u2 armhf [upgradable from: 0.14.0-2]
opensc-pkcs11/oldoldstable 0.16.0-3+deb8u2 armhf [upgradable from: 0.14.0-2]
openssl/oldoldstable 1.0.1t-1+deb8u12 armhf [upgradable from: 1.0.1t-1+deb8u7]
patch/oldoldstable 2.7.5-1+deb8u3 armhf [upgradable from: 2.7.5-1]
python-apt/oldoldstable 0.9.3.13 armhf [upgradable from: 0.9.3.12]
python-apt-common/oldoldstable 0.9.3.13 all [upgradable from: 0.9.3.12]
python-libxml2/oldoldstable 2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u8 armhf [upgradable from: 2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u5]
python-openssl/oldoldstable 0.14-1 armhf [upgradable from: 0.13.1-2]
python-xdg/oldoldstable 0.25-4+deb8u1 all [upgradable from: 0.25-4]
python3-apt/oldoldstable 0.9.3.13 armhf [upgradable from: 0.9.3.12]
rsync/oldoldstable 3.1.1-3+deb8u2 armhf [upgradable from: 3.1.1-3]
rsyslog/oldoldstable 8.4.2-1+deb8u3 armhf [upgradable from: 8.4.2-1+deb8u2]
sudo/oldoldstable 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u7 armhf [upgradable from: 1.8.10p3-1+deb8u4]
tzdata/oldoldstable 2019c-0+deb8u1 all [upgradable from: 2017b-0+deb8u1]
tzdata-java/oldoldstable 2019c-0+deb8u1 all [upgradable from: 2017b-0+deb8u1]
unifi/stable 5.12.35-12979-1 all [upgradable from: 5.6.22-10205]
unzip/oldoldstable 6.0-16+deb8u6 armhf [upgradable from: 6.0-16+deb8u3]
vim/oldoldstable 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4 armhf [upgradable from: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3]
vim-common/oldoldstable 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4 armhf [upgradable from: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3]
vim-runtime/oldoldstable 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4 all [upgradable from: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3]
vim-tiny/oldoldstable 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u4 armhf [upgradable from: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3]
wget/oldoldstable 1.16-1+deb8u7 armhf [upgradable from: 1.16-1+deb8u4]
wpasupplicant/oldoldstable 2.3-1+deb8u9 armhf [upgradable from: 2.3-1+deb8u5]
xdg-utils/oldoldstable 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-7.4+deb8u1 all [upgradable from: 1.1.0~rc1+git20111210-7.4]
```

Comment: You won't be able to undo that mess. Start again with a fresh SDCard and a copy of plain Raspbian Buster.

Comment: Doing what you describe should not have resulted in what you are seeing.  It's likely you did more than you describe.  I agree with @Dougie in that it's safest to start from scratch.

Comment: Please add more information. "What you have done?", "Result of `apt update`?" etc.

Comment: Can anyone explain the exact problem here?

Comment: You are using oldoldstable which is Raspbian Jessie. This isn't supported since 2020-01-01 anymore so I do not see a great chance to repair it. It has no future. You cannot modify it without the risk to break it. You should take the chance to change to Rasbian Buster now.

Comment: OK, so I don't get what the problem is then (Or what am I seeing), so these are Jessie updates and not stretch updates, Yes? Then that is good, Yes? So then I have no issue? I currently want to stay on Jessie, so these updates are OK and I should apt-get upgrade? Main thing I run is Unifi Controller, it appears to be have java memory issues (what doesn't)

Comment: Why downvoted? seriously!

Comment: These are probably the stretch packages(you could checkthe version numbers in the repos) and you should upgrade. Having an old system that is connected to the internet is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the Raspbian Stretch repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then did an `sudo apt-get update`. This only gets the package lists and does not install or upgrade any software. Then you commented the Stretch repository in the sources.list and do an `sudo apt-get update` again. Because the Stretch repository isn't found the in the sources.list anymore, then only its package lists are deleted so you only have the package lists from the outdated Jessie repository as before. If you haven't done a `sudo apt full-upgrade` after the first `apt-get update` with the Stretch package lists then nothing is lost or mixed up. You should have only the Jessie repository package lists. This also indicates `apt list --upgradable` you have given. It shows that are several versions from oldoldstable (Jessie) are upgradable. There are many upgrades so it seems you do not have never done it before.

If you really want to upgrade Jessie because you haven't never done it in the past you should

1. ensure that you only have the Jessie repositories addressed in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. take a backup from the SD Card (that is always a good idea)
3. ensure that you can successful restore the backup
4. do `sudo apt update`
5. do `sudo apt full-upgrade`
6. reboot

Good luck ;-)

Comment: What a fantastic Answer.
You exactly understood my problem and gave me what I can see looks like the perfect advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Shame I got down voted for my question, some people in these stckxchngs have issues, and are more interested in scolding people than helping the greater community.

Comment: @NZDev Don't worry about the down vote. It's only -2 reputations. I think it's only because of still using Jessie.

Comment: I hear you... but for someone new to the community it makes for a bad experience. and me still using Jessie is not a Bad Question, and it only just stopped being supported. It gives the person answering the question the chance to say "hey stop using Jessie", which is then good for the community. that was part of the reason for the question, ultimately I knew I needed to move forwards, but I did not want to in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

I would add this as a comment, but I can't due to 'reputation' limitations.

Any time you have these package levels, check to make sure you don't have conflicting/additional deb sources listed in any /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* files.

I find a "grep -R ^deb /etc/apt" can provide these additional insights.

If you find conflicts, you can comment/modify them as appropriate.